# What do you call a noun phrase separated from a sentence by a comma?

Tags: grammar

Consider this sentence:

> **An avid reader himself**, John always asks new acquaintances what books they read.

What do you call this construction in English grammar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> *An avid reader himself, John always asks new acquaintances what books*
> *they read*.

The most appropriate term for the noun phrase "an avid reader himself" is predicative adjunct. It's predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "John", and it's an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure (not noun phrase structure).

It is, more specifically, a supplement, detached by intonation or punctuation from the rest of the sentence. Compare the predicative complement equivalent: *John is an avid reader himself.*

Note that predicative adjuncts are not restricted to noun phrases. You can also have preposition phrases or adjective phrases:

> *In a bad temper, as usual, John walked on ahead of the main party*.
> (PP)
>
> *Angry at his mistreatment, Ed resigned*. (AdjP)